# How do i implement google fit api in .net web app with user sign in?

Tags: asp.net, rest, authentication, google-fit

I simply want to use google fit api to retrieve data of the signed in user(testing with two accounts).
But I don't understand how to get the authorization code/access token from the user.

Another possibly related problem, the consent page that list the scopes used doesn't appear.

I tried to use google.auth library

```
UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets()
                {
                    ClientId = " *** ",
                    ClientSecret = " *** "
                }, new[] { FitnessService.Scope.FitnessActivityRead, FitnessService.Scope.FitnessActivityWrite, FitnessService.Scope.FitnessSleepRead, FitnessService.Scope.FitnessSleepWrite },
                "user", CancellationToken.None);
            FitnessService fitnessService = new FitnessService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApplicationName = "Exrecise App",
                HttpClientInitializer = credential
            });
            var resp = await fitnessService.Users.Sessions.List("me").ExecuteAsync();
```

But it takes me to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVHsL.jpg) error, maybe I entered wrong inputs in console.cloud

Then, I copied the token from outhplayground and pasted it into httpclient

```
HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
            var resp = await http.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                RequestUri = new UriBuilder("https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/sessions").Uri,
                Headers =
                {
                    { "Authorization","Bearer ya29.token" } 
                },
                Method = HttpMethod.Get
            });
```

This actually got me the results I wanted, but I want to get it from the user signing in.

Question: Can I not use the regular google authentication to achieve this? Or do I have to use the former method?

Here is me adding google authentication

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(options =>
{
    IConfigurationSection auth = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
    options.ClientId = auth["ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = auth["ClientSecret"];
    options.CallbackPath = "/Home";
    options.AuthorizationEndpoint += "?prompt=consent";
});
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is that you did not supply a redirect uri (https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Apis/latest/Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ICodeReceiver)

in GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync.

You need to add a redirect uri in the Google App and add it to the codeReceiver field. that's where the user will be redirected after accepting the app.

You can find more about machine authorization and OAuth2.0 authentication with google [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#handlingresponse)